# Vertical align icon and text list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have had this problem various times and never really quite know the best way to approach it.

A screenshot for a better context:

[image]

**What it should look like...**

[image]

```
.container {
max-width: 360px;
font-size: 16px;
}
.talking-point {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: table;
    background-image: url('http://s28.postimg.org/yozkg6ueh/speech_bubble.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 45%;
    min-height: 35px;
    i {
        padding-left: 10px;
        line-height: 27px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    p {
        padding-left: 18px;
    display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }
}
```

Please check out the fiddle here *Updated as per the below*:
http://jsfiddle.net/67AD7/

Now my question is, how do I achieve a 'better' vertical-alignment between the icon and text in this situation. I'm almost tempted to use a table or should I use a list?

Note, I need to be able to insert HTML ('post-count') over the icon as in the examples provided.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: in your i{} style add : font-size:25px;

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. You want us to 'better' the vertical alignment... in what way? First, (dumb but necessary question) are you referring to the icon's relationship with the text to the side, or to the icon's relationship with its post count (or both)? And are you looking for them to be vertically centered, or vertically aligned to the top?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you for your time. I guess I'm just looking for your advice on how vertical centering in this situation is best achieved. I'm referring to both the icon's relationship with the post-count. And with the icon & post-count's relationship with the text to the side. I basically want the icon & post-count to be vertically centered according to the height of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You'll basically have to assigned the background to the **i tag**. Your CSS ends up looking like below:

```
.talking-point {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: table;
  min-height: 35px;
  i {
    background: url('http://s28.postimg.org/yozkg6ueh/speech_bubble.png') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 8px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
  }
  p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xNTh9/

Comment: Thanks for your solution Emile. I had to add the display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle, to the i tag as well for the icon to show as without it, the i wasn't taking the necessary height.

It still feels a bit weird though, can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KbyL9/

Comment: I noticed you didn't added a **width: 35px**, a **height: 35px**, and a **line-height: 30px** to the **i tag**. If you make those changes it should work fine without you having to use **display: table-cell** and **vertical-align: middle** as you mentioned.

Comment: I have to add padding to it for the whole icon image to show. From a responsive perspective table cell and middle align work quite well. I think I'll stick with this. Would love to know an easier way of achieving such a simple thing in any case. There must be a better way to approach this? Thanks for your help.